# AWS Cloudformation - mount to existing file system

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Currently, I have a json that will create a EFS in an auto scaling group. However, how can I make it so it mounts an existing EFS that is previously created (so i can pre-load data)

this is the current set up

```
"FileSystem": {
  "Type": "AWS::EFS::FileSystem",
  "Properties": {
    "PerformanceMode": "generalPurpose",
    "FileSystemTags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": { "Ref" : "VolumeName" }
      }
    ]
  }
},
"MountTarget": {
  "Type": "AWS::EFS::MountTarget",
  "Properties": {
    "FileSystemId": { "Ref": "FileSystem" },
    "SubnetId": { "Ref": "Subnet" },
    "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "MountTargetSecurityGroup" } ]        
  }
},
```

Comment: Just pass `FileSystemId` as a parameter into your CF template and use `Ref` to point to the parameter instead to the `FileSystem` resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @MaiKaY Suggested, Just Pass the FileSystemId as a Parameter.

here is the mounting Script

```
container_commands:
  1chown:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /wpfiles"
  2create:
    command: "sudo -u webapp mkdir -p wp-content/uploads"
  3link:
    command: "sudo -u webapp ln -s /wpfiles wp-content/uploads"
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    FILE_SYSTEM_ID: 'FileSystemId'  #Provide your FileSystemId
    MOUNT_DIRECTORY: '/wpfiles'
    REGION: '`{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}`'

packages:
  yum:
    nfs-utils: []
    jq: []

commands:
  01_mount:
    command: "/tmp/mount-efs.sh"

files:
  "/tmp/mount-efs.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      content : |
        #!/bin/bash

        EFS_REGION=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.REGION')
        EFS_MOUNT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.MOUNT_DIRECTORY')
        EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.FILE_SYSTEM_ID')

        echo "Mounting EFS filesystem ${EFS_DNS_NAME} to directory ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} ..."

        echo 'Stopping NFS ID Mapper...'
        service rpcidmapd status &> /dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            echo 'rpc.idmapd is already stopped!'
        else
            service rpcidmapd stop
            if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
                echo 'ERROR: Failed to stop NFS ID Mapper!'
                exit 1
            fi
        fi

        echo 'Checking if EFS mount directory exists...'
        if [ ! -d ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} ]; then
            echo "Creating directory ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} ..."
            mkdir -p ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo 'ERROR: Directory creation failed!'
                exit 1
            fi
        else
            echo "Directory ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} already exists!"
        fi

        mountpoint -q ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 ${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID}:/ ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}"
            mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 ${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID}:/ ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
            if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
                echo 'ERROR: Mount command failed!'
                exit 1
            fi
            chmod 777 ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
            runuser -l  ec2-user -c "touch ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}/it_works"
            if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
                echo 'ERROR: Permission Error!'
                exit 1
            else
                runuser -l  ec2-user -c "rm -f ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}/it_works"
            fi
        else
            echo "Directory ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} is already a valid mountpoint!"
        fi

        echo 'EFS mount complete.'
```

Comment: Where does this mounting script go?